# preventDefault() Method not Working in arrow function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a text input and submit button I need to prevent the default behavior of reloading page when clicking on submit button.
it works fine in normal function syntax **but i want to understand why not working in arrow function!**

```js
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');

todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

addTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Not working')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="todo-input">
        <button type="submit" class="todo-button">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You're defining the function but you don't appear to be adding it with `addEventListener`...

Comment: `addTodo`, OK you have a function. Where are you actually calling it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener - Also, your `<form>` get submitted. Have you noticed that your page refreshes? You need to decide. Do you want a submit action with page refresh? Or use AJAX? (Or both?)

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but if you don't want to submit the form on click, use `button type="button"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `IDs` instead of class if you have only one TODO app.
- Use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)  to assign a callback to an Event
- Don't use `<form>` if you don't submit anything to the server
- Use AJAX if you want to submit some data to the server
- Use `Form.addEventListener("submit", evt => {evt.preventDefault(); /*rest here */});` if you decide to use both `<form>` and AJAX
- Always use `type="button"` for `<button>` elements if you don't want to trigger the browser default button's "submit" form Action.

Here's an example without the form:

```js
const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

const EL_input = EL('#todo-input');
const EL_add   = EL('#todo-add');
const EL_list  = EL('#todo-list');

const addTodo = evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  const text = EL_input.value.trim();
  if (!text) return alert("Please Enter a TODO");
  EL_list.prepend(ELNew("li", { textContent: text }));
  EL_input.value = ""; // reset value.
};

EL_add.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" id="todo-input">
<button type="button" id="todo-add"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>
```